# Programming Software for making a simple, Open source web browser for noobs

Tags: open-source, web-development, web-browser, data-visualization, content-filtering

I want an application that can make a web browser with basic browsing capabilities that I can develop later on into something like google.

Must-Have:

_ A way to transfer all the saved files of code to other programming platforms for further development.

_ Multilanguage IDE

_The capability to code machine learning ( audio and video classification, conversational AI )

_ A High filtering capabilities to make structured data

_ IUX Design capabilities

_ Capable of working on any operating system (IOS, Android, Windows...etc.).

_must be Free, or have a low price (price lower than 50$, or a fee less than 20$)

Optional:

_ custom web browser can be fully own by the user without being bound by a contract

_storage 100GB

I have novice coding skills, and I'm still in the process of exploring resources (so I haven't tried anything yet).
I was hoping to get an opinion on whether I should use Android studio, Visual studio, or Linux, or if there are any other better recommendations that I can use as a start to making my web browser?

Comment: *The capability to code AI*  What does that exactly means? (I defended a PhD in AI in Paris, France in 1990) *Programming Software for making a simple, Open source web browser for noobs*  In 2022, a fully compliant web browser cannot be *simple*. For example, [Mozilla Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/1346369) has several dozens of millions of C++ code. You could study the source code of [Dillo](https://www.dillo.org/), but it is not fully compliant with all the latest standards. Contact me by email (at home, near Paris in France) to `basile@starynkevitch.net` for more details.

Comment: Realistically, if you have "novice coding skills", most of what you are asking for here will not really be doable.  The best idea is to just start learning to program with smaller tasks and defer consideration of this until you have developed your skills a good bit more.

Comment: What I mean by AI is the machine learning part where I can use deep fake, audio and visual classifiers as well as conversational AI. I'm willing to learn any common coding language (like python, Java, C++…. etc.) to make what I want, but for now  I'm searching for programming software's so that I can save myself time looking for it in the future.  though no coding prosses is technically simple, It would be Ideal to have an IDE that is multi-language so that no matter what coding language I decide to learn first I can implement it into something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the software you need is a programming language that lends itself to experimentation, such as Python, and a suitable platform. Any of IOS, Linux or Windows (not necessarily in this order of preference) would do as a platform. Start by making a basic browser. Then go from there.

There are hundreds of examples of almost anything you might want to do at this point in your career, on the 'net. In fact, one of the tasks of becoming a programmer or software developer is that of ferreting out information about what is possible and what works.